# Why did the Gradle Daemon die?

Tags: gradle, gradle-daemon

How do I determine why my Gradle Daemon died? The only message I get isL

```
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
```

This occurs in an active build. Several steps will finish and a step will appear to be active and then the build fails.

This began after moving our memory args (`Xmx` `Xms` `PermGen`) from a shell script that called `gradlew` to `gradle.properties` and calling `gradlew` directly.

**`build.sh`**

```
export GRADLE_OPTS="\"-Xmx1024m\" \"-Xms256m\" \"-XX:MaxPermSize=256m\""
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.6"
exec ./gradlew "$@"
```

**Addition to `gradle.properties`**

```
org.gradle.java.home=/usr/local/java/jdk1.6/
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

After this change Gradle warns:

```
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
```

And even though we don't ask it to, the build is running in a daemon, which ultimately fails.

Comment: Is this a consistent failure? Running gradle with --info or --debug flags might give you a hint for that

Comment: How long since you last built something using the daemon, before it died?

Comment: It is fairly consistent. I am going to try with --info or --debug, but my assumption was I won't get much because the process will not have the info it is the daemon that has it.

Comment: @Jolta I should have noted that this happens mid-build. This build takes 3.5 hours when successful. Sometimes it fails 17 min in sometimes a couple hours in. There are some predictable patterns but I don't know what to fix.

Comment: Guess it is `OutOfMemory` :) Can you post the relevant diff of build script and gradle.properties?

Comment: @barti_ddu Great suggestion and I have done so. Now that I have added it I wonder if the spaces could be an issue.

Comment: @JacobTomaw: nope, your settings look ok. However, make sure that they are not overridden somewhere (e.g. AFAIR `~/.gradle` has precedence against project directory).

Answer (score 1):

`Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly` most frequently occurs when something else kills the long-running Gradle Daemon process and the client process (the Daemon uses local TCP connections to communicate) tries to send a message and gets no response.

For example, running `gradle --stop` or `killall java` while a build is occurring will reproduce this problem.